# port in URL constructor

Tags: java

I want to check which port is used, when the port is not explicitly specified in the URL constuctor. SO here is a code.

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt");
    System.out.println("URL :"+url.getPort());
```

getPort() returned -1. It indicates that I have not set the port thats why grtPort() had returned the -1 value.

In java doc of **java.net.URL** class

> "If the port is not specified in URL, the default port for the
>   protocol is used instead.  The default port for http is 80."

Then in the above case it should have returned the 80 default port. Isn't it ?
But it is not. 
So how do I know which port is being used for the connection?

Comment: I *guess* the **URL** here means the **URL string**, not the `java.net.URL` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this example gives **default ports for their respective services. I have shown http, and ftp here.**

**Eg:**

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){



try {
System.out.println(new URL("http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt").getDefaultPort());

System.out.println(new URL("ftp://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt").getDefaultPort());


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get default pot there is a method `getDefaultPort()` inside **java.net.URL** class

use this

```
int port  = new URL("http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt").getDefaultPort();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `url.getDefaultPort()`.

Comment: soit means http port 80 is used. which will be returned by url.getDefaultPort().

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Which kind of request you are sending.

the default ports for different protocols are different.

```
20 & 21: File Transfer Protocol (FTP)
22: Secure Shell (SSH)
23: Telnet remote login service
25: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)
53: Domain Name System (DNS) service
80: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) used in the World Wide Web
110: Post Office Protocol (POP3)
119: Network News Transfer Protocol (NNTP)
143: Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP)
161: Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP)
443: HTTP Secure (HTTPS)
```